# Try to migrate Bitcoin Core wallet to an HD wallet but get "St13runtime" exception

Tags: bitcoin-core, bip32-hd-wallets, wallet.dat

I am trying to follow these [steps](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/61025) to migrate my wallet to an HD wallet. But it failed, the debug log has errors like this:

```
EXCEPTION: St13runtime_error
DeriveNewSeed: AddKeyPubKey failed
bitcoin in AppInit()
```

After some quick search, I found the [`#issue14422`](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/14422) of bitcoin is related to this issue, which says the `upgradewallet` option does not work when the wallet is encrypted. The issue is still open and no solution is given. So how can I upgrade my wallet to the HD wallet?

Answer (score 1):

The answer you linked explains how to migrate without using `upgradewallet` in the section "Versions of Bitcoin Core prior to 0.17`. You will need to follow those steps instead.

Comment: I am using the latest v0.18.1, is it safe to follow these pre-0.17 steps?

Comment: Yes it is safe.

Comment: I see, one more question, can I reduce the transaction fee to 0? And can I import my old BTC address to the new wallet so I can continue use it?

Comment: No, you cannot reduce the transaction fee to 0. Yes, you can import your old private keys into the new wallet to continue to use them. However this is not recommended as it is address reuse (which is not recommended for privacy reasons).

Comment: Thanks. My old address is published on the web for a while, so I want to monitor it in case of any income coming in the future.